# Permitir Sólo 9 enteros y dos decimales C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Necesito un textbox el cual permita sólo 9 enteros, un punto y 2 decimales
**Esto es lo que he intentado en el evento KeyDown del textbox: (txt_costo es mi textbox)**

```
 private void NumerosDecimales_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        /* Aqui hago que sólo permita números*/ 
        if (e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9 || e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9 || e.Key == Key.OemPeriod)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.OemPeriod && textBox.Text.IndexOf('.') != -1)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        /* Aqui hago la validación de los dos decimales*/ 
        bool IsDec = false;
        int nroDec = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < txt_costo.Text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (txt_costo.Text[i] == '.')
                IsDec = true;

            if (IsDec && nroDec++ >= 2)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

> **Problema:** Si el usuario escribe digamos 2 enteros, el punto y dos decimales, y necesita agregar un entero más no lo deja, porque la validación de los decimales al ya estar completa no le deja escribir nada más... Cosa que no quiero, quiero que aunque ya se hayan completado los decimales aun le permita editar los enteros hasta el máximo de 9

> **Pregunta:** ¿Existe alguna otra forma de hacer lo que necesito? Crear un textbox que sólo permita 9 enteros, un punto y 2 decimales

> **Nota:** No puedo utilizar un maskedtextbox, debe ser un textbox normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que te complicas mucho usando el evento KeyDown. Para estos casos es más útil usar los eventos  [Validating](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=netframework-4.8) y [Validated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validated?view=netframework-4.8).

En tu caso debes detectar varias cosas:

1. Que el campo no esté vacío.
2. Que no te ingresen caracteres que no sean numéricos.
3. Que solo puedan ingresar un punto decimal; pero que no esté posicionado al inicio o final del texto, sino, en el medio.

Entonces creamos un método llamado "ValidDecimal", esta función detecta:

- Que no haya un punto al inicio o final del texto.
- Que solo haya un punto decimal, de lo contrario, dará error.
- Valida que solo se ingrese caracteres numéricos.

```
        private bool ValidDecimal()
        {
            int count = 0, len = txtCosto.Text.Length;
            //Si el punto está en el inicio o final del texto ...
            if (txtCosto.Text[0] == '.' || txtCosto.Text[len - 1] == '.')
                return false;
            for(int i = 0; i != len; ++i)
            {
                //Si es un punto, contamos ...
                if (txtCosto.Text[i] == '.')
                    ++count;
                //Si no es un caracter númerico ...
                else if (!(txtCosto.Text[i] >= '0' && txtCosto.Text[i] <= '9'))
                    return false;

                if (count > 1) //Si hay más de un punto decimal.
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Ahora, creamos otro método para validar que sólo te ingresen hasta 9 enteros o dos decimales. Esta función permite que puedas ingresar únicamente enteros (sin punto decimal) o números decimales (como máximo 2 decimales).

```
        private bool CountIntsOrPoint()
        {
            int len = txtCosto.Text.Length;
            int count = 0;
            bool point = false;
            for (int i = 0; i != len; ++i)
            {
                ++count;
                if(txtCosto.Text[i] == '.')
                {
                    count = 0;
                    point = true;
                }
                    //Si hay más de 9 enteros o más de dos decimales.
                else if((point && count > 2) || (!point && count > 9)) 
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

El uso de estos métodos, sería de esta forma:

```
        private void txtCosto_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtCosto.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                msgError.SetError(txtCosto, "Campo vacío!");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else if (!ValidDecimal() || !CountIntsOrPoint())
            {
                msgError.SetError(txtCosto, "Solo se permite el ingreso hasta 9 enteros, un punto y dos decimales.");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

        private void txtCosto_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            msgError.SetError(txtCosto, "");
        }
```

**EDIT:**

No me había dado cuenta que los eventos validating y validated no existe en WPF; sin embargo, con el evento [Keyboard.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.previewlostkeyboardfocus?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) se puede mandar un mensaje de error si no se cumple la validación. Dado que este evento se llama cuando está en proceso de perderse el foco y con la propiedad `Handled` podemos establecerla en `true` para que el foco se quede en el TextBox donde ocurrió el error de validación.

El código quedaría así:

```
        private void txtCosto_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtCosto.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Campo vacío!");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (!ValidDecimal() || !CountIntsOrPoint())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Solo se permite el ingreso hasta 9 enteros, un punto y dos decimales.");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Es posible utilizar el evento Validating en WPF?, soy un poco nuevo en c#, investigué un poco y creo que no hay forma de implementar el evento "Validating" o "Validated" en WPF... ¿Hay alguna equivalencia?

Comment: @HumbertoArciniega Nunca había usado WPF, por eso no me di cuenta que los eventos validating y validated no existía en esa biblioteca. Pero usando PreviewLostKeyboardFocus podemos emular el evento validating, aunque no es exactamente lo mismo. Espero que te sirva la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar regex para verificar si es un numero con N dígitos y contiene N dígitos después de la coma flotante.

```
//donde n es el numero de digitos que quieres
var validacion = new Regex(@"^\d{n}*\.\d{n}$");

if(validation.IsMatch(e))
{
   //condición valida
} 
else 
{
   // condición falsa
}
```

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y el problema es que no siempre va a cumplir la validación porque no siempre van a estar escritos los 9 enteros y los 2 decimales, por lo que no me deja siquiera escribir algo, ya que  si solo escribo un "1", claro, no cumple la condición ¿Cómo podria solucionarlo en ese caso? (Por cierto, tuve que eliminar el * porque me mandaba error)

Comment: puedes ponerle un rango a la expresion \d{1, n} o \d[0-9]{1, n}